# Not enough information was provided to fully specify the output of the NetEncoder

Tags: neural-networks

I using a UNET combined with a VGG16 network based loss function.  The input of the UNET has an image netencoder attached to it, the output has an image netdecoder attached to it.  The loss function has the same image netencoder attached to its two inputs.

I can set-up and initialize the network without problems.  When the NetTrain function is called, I get the following warning :

```
NetEncoder::decnfs: Not enough information was provided to fully specify the output of the NetEncoder.
```

However, the training of the network starts anyway and proceeds as it should.  I could not find any information what the warning is about.

Below are two images showing the network and the loss function used, with information about the netencoders attached to the inputs.  The training samples used are monochrome images of 256x256 pixels.

I can't figure out which information is missing to fully specify the output of the NetEncoder. I am running this using MMA 12.2

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Hi there, welcome! Do you think the code used to produce the neural net can be added to the question here? Without seeing the actual net, we can't really say much about it...